# Mockk test is failing after upgrading gradle and kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I have an Android Studio project that hadn't been updated for a while. I upgraded from gradle 4.x to 8.x and from Kotlin 1.4 to 1.8. After doing so, the following test fails and I can't figure out why. Other tests are passing.

In the test below, cb is a callback that is called if there is an error loading the data.

```
it("test desc") {
    val cb: ((CustomError?) -> Unit) = mockk()
    every { cb.invoke(any()) } just Runs
    myClass.loadData(MyOptions.Init(), null, cb)
    verifyOrder {
        harness.miController.sendEvent(BaseEvent.LOAD_DATA, any(), any())
        if (resolve) {
            cb.invoke(any()) wasNot Called
        } else {
            cb.invoke(CustomError.LOAD_DATA)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using:

- io.mockk:mockk:1.13.7
- io.mockk:mockk-android:1.12.0

When I step through the tests, when resolve is true cb.invoke is not being called and when resolve is false, cb.invoke is called with the error. So it looks like it should pass, but it gets reported as failing.

The library itself is functioning correctly, so it appears to be a problem with the test.

Any ideas why it fails and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wasNot` is not intended to be used like this, it is to check whether object (mock, spy) as a whole have any registered calls

that means when you write
`cb.invoke(any()) wasNot Called` you are actually checking if **object returned by *invoke*** has been called

If you do not have any other calls to `cb` you can simply change to `cb wasNot Called`

Comment: That fixed it, thanks for your help!